# Use environment variable to specify part of image path in Lyx figures

Tags: graphics, lyx

Suppose I set an environment variable that contain an OS dependent file path 
`(e.g. /User/Dropbox/Project1/Images on Mac and C:\Users\Dropbox\Project1/Images on Windows)`
How would I go about using that environment variable as part of the image path `(e.g./User/Dropbox/Project1/Images/image_of_interest.pdf on Mac and C:\Users\Dropbox\Project1/Images/image_of_interest.pdf on Windows)` when adding a graphics object using Lyx?

I understand that relative path can be used to specify path of "image_of_interest.pdf" in an OS independent manner. However, since I'm using Cryptomator to encrypt the enclosing folder of the Lyx file and load the encrypted folder as a virtual drive and "image_of_interest.pdf" is outside of the encrypted folder, I can only think of specifying an absolute path to "image_of_interest.pdf" in an OS independent way using environment variables.

Comment: I understand the desire to use encrypted or cloud folders for documentation but bitter experience has taught me its safer to pull the contents local for editing then return them to the container once done. this is not just for compilation but the file handling of background converters  (dvi/ps/eps/pdf) or viewers (synctex)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the difficulties you faced in addition to screwing up relative paths that point to outside of the encrypted folder? I'm new to encrypting cloud folders.

Comment: Versioning's no help if your eggs are in same basket. Loss is simply greater, 40+yrs ago lost data on encoded floppies 30-20 yrs ago lost data on remote mainframes. Last yr, lost months of work on secure backup-system that takes just as long to rebuild so re-started from scratch, This week lost 1.5 TB of history & wondering if the recovery struggle is worth it. Tex files are plain snippets. The more encrypted the more difficult to recover easily if needed. A zip file or any other method (usb that glitched / pulled / spiked by power surge) is only as good as the # of copies in event of failure.

Comment: Whilst editing the files are in a delicate state, especially there are many requests how can I recover my Tex from the final PDF since my file is no longer in the ether /usb stick. During edits the file is fully open thus prone to corruption from many causes, whilst running the compilation numerous file handling processes are in action. it only takes one byte to go wrong and the whole tower crumbles. Viewers during compilation need unfettered access to the updates etc. Thus frequently am asked why does this system not synchronise in dropbox/google/one drive etc. Backup off-line & expect issues